# C opy file3.txt to f older down level three, file4.txt to four

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory like this

```
C:\folder11\
C:\folder21\
C:\folder11\folder12\
C:\folder11\folder12\folder13\
C:\folder21\folder22\folder23\
C:\folder31\folder32\folder33\
C:\folder11\folder12\folder13\folder14\
C:\folder11\folder12\folder13\folder14\folder15\
```

I have file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt, file5.txt,...

I want to have this.

```
C:\folder11\file1.txt
C:\folder21\file1.txt
C:\folder11\folder12\file2.txt
C:\folder11\folder12\folder13\file3.txt
C:\folder21\folder22\folder23\file3.txt
C:\folder31\folder32\folder33\file3.txt
C:\folder11\folder12\folder13\folder14\file4.txt
C:\folder11\folder12\folder13\folder14\folder15\file5.txt
```

Could you Please make for file3.txt ,and file4.txt,... copied to each specific folders in that current directory?

Thank You Very Much.......

Comment: `file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt, file5.txt,...` <--- are they really the filenames?  A fairly simple solution is possible but the filename format is important.

Comment: Thank foxidrive, file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt, file5.txt,...   are not really the file names. but Please assume that they are really file names.

Comment: I still need to know the format of the filenames.  if there is no common format then the task has to be written for the exact filenames.

Comment: The format of file is *.ini . Please help me. The all files I need to copy and place is *.ini.

Comment: Please make one program for file3.txt and another one program for file4.txt. Thank You.

Comment: The filenames is the important part.  What are they called?  Are they all in a format of "name_number.ini" or are the names all entirely different?

Comment: They have the same format but file names are different.

Comment: Please make program for file3.txt and program for file4.txt as the program for file2.txt as shown in above. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`COPY file path`

Like this but for all of them

`COPY "file5.txt" "C:\folder11\folder12\folder13\folder14\folder15\"`

Answer (score 0):

This assumes a root directory is the base level.  Each line has an `echo copy` command which will just show you on the console what it will copy.  Remove the `echo` from each line to perform the file copy.

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr \\.*\\                  ^| findstr /v \\.*\\.*\\                ') do echo copy "file1.txt" "%%~fa"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr \\.*\\.*\\              ^| findstr /v \\.*\\.*\\.*\\            ') do echo copy "file2.txt" "%%~fa"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr \\.*\\.*\\.*\\          ^| findstr /v \\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\        ') do echo copy "file3.txt" "%%~fa"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr \\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\      ^| findstr /v \\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\    ') do echo copy "file4.txt" "%%~fa"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr \\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\  ^| findstr /v \\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\') do echo copy "file5.txt" "%%~fa"
pause
popd
```

Comment: I found one reference site I want to share, http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true